# str.format(list) with negative index doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I use a negative index in replacement fields to output a formatted list,but it raises a TypeError.The codes are as follows:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> a[2]
3
>>> a[-1]
3
>>> 'The last:{0[2]}'.format(a)
'The last:3'
>>> 'The last:{0[-1]}'.format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: sounds like an oversight in the format functions definition

Comment: The relevant bug in Python's bugbase - http://bugs.python.org/issue7951. In short, the issue is being treated as a documentation bug because of the side-effects of implementing this and also the fact that it may lead to bad code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's what I would call a design glitch in the format string specs.  Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax),

```
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
```

but, alas, `-1` is not "an integer" -- it's an expression.  The unary-minus operator doesn't even have particularly high priority, so that for example `print(-2**2)` emits `-4` -- another common issue and arguably a design glitch (the `**` operator has higher priority, so the raise-to-power happens first, then the change-sign requested by the lower priority unary `-`).

Anything in that position in the format string that's not an integer (but, for example, an expression) is treated as a string, to index a dict argument -- for example:

```
$ python3 -c "print('The last:{0[2+2]}'.format({'2+2': 23}))"
The last:23
```

Not sure whether this is worth raising an issue in the Python trac, but it's certainly a somewhat surprising behavior:-(.

Comment: Interesting! As for -2**2 being equal to -4, I think this is a very good thing, as this is the convention used in mathematics. Would something like element_index ::= "signed_integer" make sense?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems here, once you start digging:

The item in question is called "element_index" which is defined to be an integer.

Problem 1: unless users follow the link from "integer" to the language reference manual, they won't know that -1 is deemed to be an expression, not an integer. By the way, anyone tempted to say "works as documented" should see proplem 7 first :-)

Preferred solution: change the definition so that "element_index" can have an optional '-' before the integer.

It's an integer, right? Not so fast ... later the docs say that "an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`"

Problem 3: Should say '[element_index]' (index is not defined).

Problem 4: Not everybody knows off the top of their heads what `__getitem__()` does. Needs clearer docs.

So we can use a dict here as well as an integer, can we? Yes, with a problem or two:

The element_index is a integer? Yes, that works with a dict:

```
>>> "{0[2]}".format({2: 'int2'})
'int2'
```

It seems that we can also use non-integer strings, but this needs more explicit documentation (Problem 5):

```
>>> "{0[foo]}".format({'foo': 'bar'})
'bar'
```

But we can't use a dict with a key like '2' (Problem 6):

```
>>> "{0[2]}".format({'2': 'str2'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 2
>>> "{0['2']}".format({'2': 'str2'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'2'"
```

Problem 7: That "integer" should really be documented to be "decimalinteger" ... 0x22 and 0b11 are treated as str, and 010 (an "octalinteger") is treated as 10, not 8:

```
>>> "{0[010]}".format('0123456789abcdef')
'a'
```

**Update:** [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) tells the true story:
"""
The rules for parsing an item key are very simple. If it starts with a digit, then it is treated as a number, otherwise it is used as a string.

Because keys are not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings "10" or ":-]") from within a format string.
"""

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it does not work. solution:

```
>>> 'The last:{0}'.format(a[-1])
'The last:3'
```

Comment: Which begs the question: so why bother with designing restricted sequence indexing, restricted dict lookup, and attribute lookup facilities in the format strings, when all that and more can be done in the args?

Answer (score 0):

I often take Python format strings as config options - with the format string provided with a specific, known list of keyword arguments.  Therefore addressing the indexes of a variable length list forwards or backwards within the format string is exactly the kind of thing I end up needing.

I've just written this hack to make the negative indexing work:

```
string_to_tokenise = "Hello_world"
tokens = re.split(r"[^A-Z\d]+", string_to_tokenise, flags=re.I)
token_dict = {str(i) if i < 0 else i: tokens[i] for i in range(-len(tokens) + 1, len(tokens))}
print "{thing[0]} {thing[-1]}".format(thing=token_dict)
```

Result:

```
Hello world
```

So to explain, instead of passing in the list of tokens, I create a dictionary with all the required integer keys for indexing the list from 0 to len(..)-1, and I also add the negative integer keys for indexing from the end from -1 to -(len(..)-1), however these keys are converted from integers to strings, as that's how format will interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively straight forward to extend the builtin [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) to allow this case. The code below adds 2 lines to the existing implementation to resolve negative indices as integers.

```
from _string import formatter_field_name_split
from string import Formatter as BuiltinFormatter


class Formatter(BuiltinFormatter):
    """
    Implements negative indexing for format fields.
    """

    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kws):
        # eg: field_name = '0[name]' or 'label.title' or 'some_keyword'
        # OR 'key[-1]' implemented here
        first, rest = formatter_field_name_split(field_name)
        obj = self.get_value(first, args, kws)

        # loop through the rest of the field_name, doing
        #  getattr or getitem as needed
        for is_attr, i in rest:
            if is_attr:
                obj = getattr(obj, i)
            else:
                # fix to allow negative indexing next two lines :)
                if i.startswith('-') and i[1:].isdigit():
                    i = int(i)
                obj = obj[i]

        return obj, first


# test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    formatter = Formatter()
    print(formatter.format('hello {worlds[-1]}!', 
                            worlds=('earth', 'mars', ..., 'world')))
```

Which outputs
`hello world!`
as desired.