# Unexpected behavior of str.format()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using templates in this manner:

```
data = {'root':{'childrens':[1,2]}}
print('{data[root][childrens][0]}'.format(**locals()))
```

Output is `1` as expected, but when I run this code:

```
print('{data[root][childrens][-1]}'.format(**locals()))
```

I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    '{data[root][childrens][-1]}'.format(**locals())
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: ```'{}'.format(data['root']['childrens'][-1])```

Comment: @ChadS. Not good for me. This is simplest possible example, just for reproduce this error. In my real code templates is more complex and I'll losing clarity of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
```

`-1` is deemed to be an `expression`, not an `integer`.

Also there is usefull information in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620237/str-formatlist-with-negative-index-doesnt-work-in-python).

Comment: I'm still puzzled. But can't argue with [PEP 3103](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) :)

Comment: @ElRuso: why are you puzzled? PEP 3103 says clearly: *"If it starts with a digit"*  and minus is not a digit. `ast.dump(ast.parse('-1', 'eval').body[0])` is `'Expr(value=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Num(n=1)))'` i.e., `-1` is an expression (unary minus operator applied to `1`). You can check that `+1` is also an expression. In Python 3.6, there are `f''` strings that allow Python expressions e.g., `f'{data["root"]["childrens"][-1]}'` (no `.format(**vars())`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was puzzled only by parser design decision. With the PEP text itself, everything is clear. `f''` in 3.6 looks cool. Tnx for interesting information

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation from [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):**

*It should be noted that the use of 'getitem' within a format string
    is much more limited than its conventional usage.  In the above example,
    the string 'name' really is the literal string 'name', not a variable
    named 'name'.  The rules for parsing an item key are very simple.
    If it starts with a digit, then it is treated as a number, otherwise
    it is used as a string.*