# Negative list index in a format string

Tags: python

The following string formatting involving list indexing works fine with positive indexes but fails with a type error  on negative indexes.
I find it surprising as negative indexing is very pythonic.
I am looking for a way to make that work or at least an explanation for why that's not possible.

```py
    format_str0  = 'some_list[0] is {some_list[0]}'
    format_str1  = 'some_list[1] is {some_list[1]}'
    format_str_1 = 'some_list[-1] is {some_list[-1]}'

    print(format_str0.format(some_list=[0, 1, 2]))   # OK - prints some_list[0] is 0
    print(format_str1.format(some_list=[0, 1, 2]))   # OK - prints some_list[1] is 1
    print(format_str_1.format(some_list=[0, 1, 2]))  # TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1620294/21303427